# Ansible: Create new user and copy ssh-keys from local system

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I'm new to Ansible and I'm struggeling with creating a new user on a remote machine and copying ssh-keys (for git) from the local machine to the remote machine's new user.
Basically, from `localmachine/somepath/keys/` to `remotemachine/newuser/home/.ssh/`.

So far I tried:

```
- name: Create user
  hosts: remote_host
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Create new user
      user: name=newuser ssh_key_file=../keys/newuser
```

While this creates the newuser on the remote machine, it doesn't copy any keys (.ssh is still empty). I also tried `authorized_key` as a second task but only got an error message when trying to copy the private key.

Is it even possible that the keys are still added after I already ran it and `newuser`already exists. Ie, can I just run it again or will I have to delete the newuser first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ssh_key_file` is the path used by the option `generate_ssh_key` of [`user` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html). It's not the path of a local SSH key to upload to the remote user created.

If you want to upload the SSH key, you have to use the [`copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html)

```
- name: Create user
  hosts: remote_host
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Create new user
      user:
        name: newuser
    - name: Create .ssh folder
      file:
        path: ~newuser/.ssh
        state: directory
        owner: newuser
        group: newuser
        mode: 0700
     - name: Upload SSH key
       copy:
        src: ../keys/newuser
        dest: ~newuser/.ssh/id_rsa
        owner: newuser
        group: newuser
        mode: 0700
```

BTW, it's recommended to use the YAML syntax instead of the args syntax.

Comment: It seems like `.ssh` was already created, so I skipped that task. But thanks for pointing me to `copy` - I was on the wrong track.